# With PyTorch, how can I pass the output of a bidirectional LSTM to a Linear layer?

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

I have:

```
    def forward(self, x, hidden=None):
        lstm_out, hidden = self.lstm(x, hidden)
        print('lstm_out.size', lstm_out.size())
        lstm_out = lstm_out.view(-1, lstm_out.shape[2])
        out = self.linear(lstm_out)
        print('out', out.size())
```

And this does not work. My `self.linear` is `self.linear = nn.Linear(64 * seq_length, 5)`. I can change the 5 to whatever later.

So the `size` of my `lstm_out` is `torch.Size([64, 20, 322])`. But then I get an error when doing the `self.linear`: `RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [1280 x 322], m2: [1280 x 5] at`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: seems like `64 * seq_length` equals 1280 but should be 322. what happens if you change that?

Comment: If I change it to `self.linear = nn.Linear(322, 5)`, then I get `RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (5) must match the size of tensor b (161) at non-singleton dimension 2`. If I change the second dimension to 161, I get `The size of tensor a (1280) must match the size of tensor b (20) at non-singleton dimension 1`